# Operand type conversion in relational operation

Tags: java

According code below I found that `int i` is promoted to `float`. Which rule defines type conversion decision in this situation?

```
int i = 5;
float f = 5.5f;
if (i == f) {...}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's at the start of [JLS 15.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) (the numeric == equality operator):

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

[JLS 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) starts (emphasis mine):

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> - If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> - Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>   - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>   - **Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.**
>   - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>   - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.